# Javascript foreach

Tags: php, javascript, foreach

I have a javascript for a usage graph , the data for the graph within the javascript is defined as follow:

```
data: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
```

I have before the javascript a foreach and a value that im trying to use in this data field as follow :

data: [],

Now if i just do echo "$test"; outside javascript on the page i get the following output
1,2,3,4,5,6, which is correct , if i copy this output and use it directly in the datafield it works BUT when I try to call the $test value within the datafield it does not work.
So in short

```
data: [1,2,3,4,5,6], (WORKS)
data: [<?php echo "$test"; ?>], (does not work even though when doing normal echo outside java it does print 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Any help would be appreciated

```
foreach ($chart->usage->days->day as $day): 
$totals = $day->total;
$datau = Round(("$totals") / (1024 * 1024 * 1024), 2);
$test = "$datau, ";
```

Comment: do you have an extra comma in the $test variable? for example [1,2,3,4,5,6,] ?

Comment: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` isn't the same of `["1,2,3,4,5,6"]`

Comment: yes i do , but even if i copy that and input into the data field it works , example
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,], (works aswel)

Comment: try to trim the extra comma, some browsers don't like it, try [<?php echo trim($test, ','); ?>]

Comment: Trailing commas are valid per ES5 spec (only fails in IE7 and below).

Comment: the trim does not work

Comment: Could you paste the code from your working code? `Round` should be `round` and `$test =` would probably be `$test .=`..

Comment: my foreach all works , as said when I do a echo "$test" i do get 1,2,3,4,5,6,

Comment: @Fabricio OK OK by doing this : $test =   to ( $test .=) it works but now on top of the page i get following error : Notice: Undefined variable: test

Comment: @StephanBotes put `$test = "";` before the `foreach`

Comment: A cleaner solution is using an array and imploding it as outlined in @hellohellosharp's answer though.

Comment: @Fabrício , cool thanks alot dude!!! it all works fine now , could you please put this as your awnser so i can accept it for you :)

Comment: Nah don't worry, @hello put a lot of effort on his answer, try his array version - it is much cleaner than building a string like that and will work even on older browsers. `:P`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
$test="1,2,3,4,5,6"; //Make sure to remove a trailing comma.
data: [<?php echo $test; ?>]
```

I don't see any need for the "$test".

Sidenote: You can take out the echo as well. Also, since `data` is an array, I would store `$test` as an array as well.

```
$test=array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
data: [<?= implode(",", $test) ?>]
```

This looks cleaner in my opinion.

Edit: Based on your foreach, please try:

```
$test=array();
foreach ($chart->usage->days->day as $day){
$totals = $day->total;
$test[] = round(($totals) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024), 2);
}

data: [<?= implode(",", $test) ?>],
```

Comment: String interpolation would have the same output as far as I can see.

Comment: but it shouldn't matter, should give the same output

Comment: Can you tell me what `var_dump($test)` looks like?

Comment: cant do like that , ive updated my question with my foreach  , maybe it will be more clear

Comment: Okay I kind of see...but why can't you just var_dump the variable to make sure you have the right output?

Comment: by doing this : $test = to ( $test .=) it works but now on top of the page i get following error : Notice: Undefined variable: test

Comment: You can get rid of that Notice by adding `$test='';` above the foreach or by using my method in my answer. It is just a Notice though so not that significant.

Comment: I'd personally prefer `data: <?php echo json_encode($test); ?>` instead of `implode`, this would handle non-numeric values and even values with comma/quotes without problems. Of course, not much difference in this case.

Comment: Not a problem. If it still doesn't work, like you said above, I would happy to take a look at your script through chat and help you fix it. I can also show you a thing or two about debugging.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté - great idea! Would there need to be an additional `;` at the end of that for the javascript? `data: <?= json_encode($test) ?>;`